# How to draw the true density (for the specified gamma distribution) on histogram

Tags: r

I want to draw the true density on histogram.
Here is my code, I'm not sure if my codes are right or not.

```
set.seed(600)
x <- rgamma(500,shape=8,scale=0.1)
mean(x)
hist(x,prob=T,main='Gamma,scale=0.1')
lines(density(x),col='red',lwd=2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: And by 'true density' do you mean the gamma distribution that you generated the values from or do you mean a kernel density estimate?  Because what you have is the second one of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`density()` gives a local estimate of the density. The *true* density can be derived from `dgamma`, and plotted like this...

```
lines( sort(x) , y = dgamma( sort(x) , shape = 8 , scale = 0.1 ) , col = "blue" , lty = 2 , lwd = 2 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
curve(dgamma(x, shape=8, scale=0.1), add=TRUE, col='blue')
```